# Increase margin-bottom on list elements to make them more legible

Tags: bug, design

List elements on other Stack Exchange sites are displayed with a `margin-bottom` of `0.5em`. Here's an example screenshot from [this UX.stackexchange answer](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/16404/5124):

[image]

But on Pro Webmasters, list items like the one from [this answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/1547/7198) look like this:

[image]

Please could `li` items on Pro Webmasters be given a margin-bottom to make them easier to read?

Comment: +1 for usability! ;)